# he maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data

Tags: wcf

I am trying to call a WCF service that reads an XML string. I get this error
"Formater error the maximum string content length quota 
(8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data." Below is the Service web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug     includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IOrderCreateService"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                     openTimeout="00:1:00"
                     closeTimeout="00:1:00"
                     sendTimeout="00:25:00"
                     receiveTimeout="00:25:00">

            </binding>

        <binding name="HandleLargeMessage" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
               maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
               maxArrayLength="2147483647"
               maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
               maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

        </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>

        <!-- beta.telagententerprise.com/WcfServices-->
        <service name="OrderCreateService.OrderCreateService">
            <endpoint name="MessageServiceEndpoint"
                      address="http://localhost:2966/OrderCreateService.svc"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="HandleLargeMessage"
                      contract="IOrderCreateService" />

        </service>

    </services>     
</system.serviceModel>
```

Below is the client side app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IOrderCreateService"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                     openTimeout="00:1:00"
                     closeTimeout="00:1:00"
                     sendTimeout="00:25:00"
                     receiveTimeout="00:25:00">

            </binding>

            <binding name="HandleLargeMessage" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                   maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                   maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                   maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                   maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint name="MessageServiceEndpoint"
                      address="http://localhost:2966/OrderCreateService.svc"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="HandleLargeMessage"
                      contract="OrderCreateService.IOrderCreateService" />


    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I searched for this error tried this code above still getting the 8192 error.
Any help would be great.
Thanks,
S

Comment: can you show your client code ?

Answer (score 0):

The server side config --> endpoint elements contract value is not fully qualified. Should be `OrderCreateService.IOrderCreateService`

Also if you are hosting on IIS the address mapping to the service is handled by IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue even after setting maxStringContentLength = "2147483647" on both client and Server .config files. After trying many suggestions in the web, it was fixed by matching the target framework on both client and the Server projects (under Project Properties/ build tab/ Platform target in Visual Studio 2013).